# Is there any way to make Django's get_or_create() to create an object without saving it to database?

Tags: django, django-models

When using Django's get_or_create(), when created=True, is there any way to
make it so that it creates an object without saving it to DB?

I want to take the newly created object, do some validation tests, and
only save it to DB if it passes all tests.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Rather than try to make get_or_create something it's not, why not just create a new @classmethod (or use a custom manager) called get_or_new(), and then only do the save() when you want to?

Comment: That sounds useful.  Wouldn't it be nice if that was in django core?

Answer (score 0):

Why not override the model's save method, and have it do the tests there? Then you don't have to make sure you use the right creation method each time.

```
class MyModel(Model)
    def save(self):
        self.run_presave_tests()
        if self.passed_tests:
            super(MyModel, self).save()
```

Comment: I don't agree: `save` method is supposed to _save_ the object. Programmers shouldn't have to think whether the object will be saved or not .